# Dart Null Safety Concept is not cleared

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

Dart null safety says that by default all variables of primitive data types (int, String, bool) are non-nullable, they can't have a null value, right? Let suppose if I have a variable 'a' of type int then I can't assign it a null value unless to use question mark with data type.

`int a=null;`

the above code will generate an error like 'The value 'null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int' because 'int' is not nullable.'

But at the same time, dart says that all initialized variables have a default value of null. My question is why statement-1 doesn't match with statement-2? Dart should not allow us to declare an uninitialzed variables because uninitialzed variables contain null value which doesn't apply with its own statement. Can anybody clear my confusion?

Comment: "by default all variables of primitive data types..." Dart does not have "primitive data types".  All types that end with a `?` are nullable and all types without are non-nullable (except for `dynamic`, which is special).  "But at the same time, dart says that all initialized variables have a default value of null." Who says?  Wherever you read that, it probably is outdated information written from before null-safety.  That statement is no longer true.

Comment: Agree. And it should probably be "all *un*initialized variables".
With null safety, uninitialized *nullable* variables have a default value of `null`. Unintialized variables with a potentially non-nullable type are just *uninitialized* and must be definitely assigned before they can be read (or just potentially assigned if the variable is `late`, with a run-time error if you read it before it's actually initialized).

Comment: @jamesdlin thank you so much for clearing my confusion, I just read the dart docs once again and it was my mistake dart says that [Uninitialized variables that have a nullable type have an initial value of null](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour). it was for nullable types variables I though for non-nullable.

Answer (score 3):

if you declare variables like this

```
int? a = null; 
int? a;
```

Both will be null;

when you put '?' after variable you are saying to dart "hey I'm okay if it's null or not"
but sometimes you won't execute some function if the variable passing to it is null so you have to declare a variable without '?' in this case you are saying to dart "hey this variable must not be null";

also, you have to do research about null checkers, because it's very important

The `?, !, ??` null checkers

I'll keep it very simple

? says It's ok if the value is null

! says it must have non null value

?? says if it's null then assign another value...

```
    String? nullableValue;

String nonNullableValue;
nonNullableValue = nullableValue; //throws error because nullable value cants be assigned to non nullable variable;

nonNullableValue = nullableValue ?? "undefined or null"// You are saying to dart "hey if nullable value null then assign "undefined or null";

nonNullableValue = nullableValue! // You are saying to dart "Hey this value Must not be null . But you have to check value for null with if condition like this

if(nullableValue !=null) {
nonNullableValue = nullableValue!;// By putting ! you are saying "don't worry dart this is checked value and its 100% not null";
}
```

The main reason for null safety is checking or preventing a variable to be null

Please read official [docs](https://dart.dev/null-safety) for more information

Comment: thank you so much for the nice explanation, but I don't want to get an explanation over it, my point is  "int nonNullable;" we can't assign null value to this variable right? but at the same time, this variable has a null value because all uninitialized variables have a default null value. This conflict confused me a lot

Comment: @MuhammadAfzal int nonNullable never gets a null value.  Even if you don’t assign a default value to its dart compiler says “hey nonNullableValue variable isn’t assigned, so im trying to give it a null value but this type of variable don't allows to give it null value,,but when you put ? After variable you saying this variable is allowed to get a null value so dart will assign a null value if its not initialised ”

Comment: I just read the dart docs once again and found this statement [Uninitialized variables that have a nullable type have an initial value of null](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#variables), I found the solution, it was my mistake actually I took it wrong, dart says that only **nullable** types have a default value of null but I though every uninitialized variable have a default value of null that's wrong.